# Counting by multiples in c byte array

Tags: c

Im trying to reduce the information density of an RGB pixel in a 2d barcode for scanning.

I currently have a 3 byte array where information is encoded in multiples of `bound` until 256 is hit, at which point it will loop over to the next byte; For instance if `bound` was 60:

```
      0,0,0 -> 60,0,0 -> 120,0,0 -> 180,0,0 -> 240,0,0 -> (loop over) 0,60,0 -> ...
```

I suspect there is a very simple method to do this, but i have only been able to implement this with a for loop

```
void multiples(uint32_t data){
  uint32_t a[3] = {0, 0, 0};
  uint8_t bound = 32;

  for(int i = 0; i < data; i++){
    a[0] += bound;
    a[1] += bound*(a[0] - a[0]%256)/256;
    a[2] += bound*(a[1] - a[1]%256)/256;

    a[0] %= 256;
    a[1] %= 256;
  }

  printf("%u,%u,%u\n",a[0],a[1],a[2]);
}
```

How should this be done optimally?

Comment: Which rule did you apply to get from `240,0,0` to `0,20,0`? Why `0,20`?

Comment: According to your code `a[0]` should be 44, and `a[1]`, 60 just after `240,0,0`.

Comment: `until 256 is hit, at which point it will loop over` If 256 is max, and you are at 240, and you add 60, and you loop over, then you should have `0,44,0` not `0,20,0`

Comment: Yes my bad, that was a typo. I was originally demonstrating with 20 but thought it took too long, so I switched to 60. I mustve forgotten to change that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not match the code and your explanation. But assuming that your code is correct, I think that we can optimize it. Since you are adding `bound` constantly to `a[0]`, the cumulative value of `a[0]` (say, `acc[0]`) will be,

```
acc[0] = data * bound
```

So `a[0]` can be directly computed as `acc[0] % 256`. Now the cumulative value of `a[1]` is adding `bound` whenever `acc[0]` crosses a multiple of 256. Therefore,

```
acc[1] = (acc[0]/256)*bound
```

So `a[1]` will be `acc[1]%256`. Cumulative `a[2]` similarly is the number of times `acc[1]` crosses a multiple of 256.

```
acc[2] = (acc[1]/256)*bound
```

I think the requirement must be `a[2]` to be less than 256, so `a[2]` should be `acc[2]%256`. But you can keep it equal to `acc[2]` as in the code.

Comment: I just noticed that, and this might be a problem in my *own* code too, when a bound of 60 is given and 5 as a value, your code returns `44,60,0` instead of `0,60,0`.

Comment: Yes it was confusing for me as well regarding what you were trying to do. So I went with optimizing your code. I still do not understand the problem statement. Maybe you can make it more clear. But I still think the answer would be somewhere along these lines.

Comment: Youre correct, and once again, sorry for the typo. Your code actually did work; I ended up swapping out 256 with a `uint8_t` equal to `bound*(256/bound)`. Thank you!